# Integration with $d($"some function"$)$ instead of $d($"some variable"$)$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, notation, indefinite-integrals

$$\int x\,d(x^2)=\;?$$
I am confused with this. Usually we have $d($"some variable"$)$, not $d($"some function"$)$.

My attempt is the following:
$$\int x\,d(x^2)=\int \sqrt{x^2}\,d(x^2)=\frac{(x^2)^{3/2}}{3/2}=\frac{2}{3}x^3.$$
But I am worried because $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\neq x$ in general.

Comment: See the [Riemann–Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).

Comment: What about $\int x\,d(x^2)=\int x\cdot\frac{d(x^2)}{dx}\,dx= \int x\cdot 2 x\,dx= \int 2x^2\,dx = \frac{2}{3} x^3$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can write
$$
\int x\,d(x^2) = \int x\Big( 2x\,dx\Big)=\cdots
$$
etc.

However, the notation
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dg(x) \tag 1
$$
is sometimes also taken to mean the [Riemann–Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) of $f$ with respect to $g$ on the interval $a\le x\le b$.  That is defined as the limit as the mesh of the partition approaches $0$, of
$$
\sum_i f(x_i^\ast)\,\Delta g(x)_i = \sum_i f(x_i^\ast)(g(x_{i+1}-g(x_i))
$$
(where $x_i^\ast$ is some point in $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$).

This integral is the same as
$$
\int_a^b f(x)g'(x)\,dx \tag 2
$$
**PROVIDED** $g'$ exists everywhere in the interval, and I think one can get by with something weaker than "everyhwere" in some cases.  **But** the Riemann–Stieltjes integral is defined even in cases where $g'$ fails to exist in many places and where the $(1)$ is *not* equal to $(2)$.  An example is the case where $g$ is the [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).  That function is everywhere continuous and its derivative is zero [almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere), Riemann–Stieltjes integral $\displaystyle\int_0^1 1\,dg(x)$ is equal to $1$.

If $f$ is some function of a random variable (capital) $X$ whose [cumulative probability distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) is $g$, then the expected value $\operatorname{E}(f(X))$ is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dg(x)
$$
regardless of whether the distribution is discrete or continuous or a mixture of the two or none of the above, and "none of the above" is exemplified by the [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution).

The Riemann–Stieltjes integral is defined only if the [total variation of the function $g$, sometimes called the "integrator", is finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation), and also only if $f$ and $g$ have no common points of discontinuity.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, $\int d(f(x))=\int f'(x) dx=f(x)$ since $df(x)=f'(x)dx$. Your work isn't wrong for when $x>0$, and you would just split it up if the region of integration included both positive and negative $x$ values.

A simpler way to look at it is that $\int x d(x^2)=\int 2x^2 dx =2x^3/3$ (as long as $x\geq0$).

Answer (score 1):

I think we can do this for $x<0$:
\begin{align}
& \text{ if } x<0 \text{ then } |x|=-x \text{ so } -|x|=x \\
&\text{ or } - (x^2)^\frac{1}{2} =x \\
&\int x \, d(x^2)=\int - (x^2)^\frac{1}{2} \, d(x^2) \\
&\text{ someone correct me If I'm wrong }\end{align}